# SwiftUI macOS sheet does not dismiss sometimes

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have implemented a sheet to edit the values of a client.

It's normally possible to edit the client and close the sheet after pressing the OK-Button. But if the sheet is open for a longer time it is not possible to dismiss the sheet. Nothing happens and they only way to proceed is to quit the program.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens sometimes?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingEditClient = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Button(action: showEditClientSheet) {
                    Text("Edit Client")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingEditClient) {
                    EditClientSheet()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 400)
    }

    func showEditClientSheet(){
        showingEditClient.toggle()
    }
}


struct EditClientSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var name = "Max"

    var body: some View {
         VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
            }
            HStack{
                Button(action: cancel) {
                    Text("Abbrechen")
                }
                Button(action: editClient) {
                    Text("Ok")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
    }

func editClient() {
        NSApp.keyWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
        //Check if content is correct to save
        if name != "" {
            //store the changes
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }else {
           //show Alert
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many errors to make your code snapshot testable. Start from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong code. I edited it.